# C++ Base64 String "Z2V0UGFzc3dvcmQ=" as function name

Tags: c++, dll, encryption

some quick info about me
I'm a MalwareResearcher since 2008 and C++/MASM Developer since 2013. Atm I improve and test my skills with malware samples and CrackMe's.

I found a really nice one and got stucked at the coding part :(

Code Snippet from crackme:

```
MOV EAX,004260AC                               ; ASCII "TUFMQ0hPLkRMTA=="
CALL 00407B10
JMP SHORT 004049FB
XOR EAX,EAX
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[LOCAL.1],-1
TEST EAX,EAX
JZ 00404AC3
MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX]
PUSH EAX                                       ; /FileName
CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&kernel32.LoadLibraryA>]   ; \KERNEL32.LoadLibraryA
TEST EAX,EAX
JZ 00404AC3
PUSH 004260C0                                  ; /Procname = "Z2V0UGFzc3dvcmQ="
PUSH EAX                                       ; |hModule
CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&kernel32.GetProcAddress>] ; \KERNEL32.GetProcAddress
```

The crackme tries to load a dll called `MALCHO.dll` with `LoadLibraryA` and then tries to execute one its functions named `Z2V0UGFzc3dvcmQ=`.

After that it decrypts one of its resources with the password gathered from the dll's function `Z2V0UGFzc3dvcmQ=`.

As a part of the crackme it seems that I have to make this dll.

I was able to get the password which is needed for decryption by analysing another part of this specimen.

So "only" dll coding is needed to reach the end of the crackme :)

While decrypting `TUFMQ0hPLkRMTA==` to `MALCHO.dll` it seems that its function name `Z2V0UGFzc3dvcmQ=` is not decrypted to `getPassword`.

I don't now how to use a base64 encoded string as a function name in c++.

I get a syntax error in cause of the `=` in `Z2V0UGFzc3dvcmQ=` :(

My `MALCHO.dll` source:

MALCHO.h:

```
#ifdef MALCHODLL_EXPORTS
#define MALCHOFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MALCHOFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

namespace MALCHO
{
    //This class is exported from the MalchoFuncsDll.dll
    class MalchoFuncs
    {
    public:
        // Returns password
        static MALCHOFUNCSDLL_API char* Z2V0UGFzc3dvcmQ=(char* p);
    };
}
```

MALCHO.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MALCHO.h"


namespace MALCHO
{
 char* MalchoFuncs::Z2V0UGFzc3dvcmQ=(char* p)
 {
    char* pw = "Yes I did it!";
    return pw;
 }
}
```

thanks in advance

MasDie

Comment: Try a linker definitions file, or directly editing the PE exports table.

Comment: Or patch the executable loading the dll if that is allowed

Comment: @Ben Voigt I think editing the import table of the crackme would be needed and not export table ?! How would a linker definition file look like in my case ?

Comment: @Paranaix patching isn't an option :/

Comment: @user3263309: No, the crackme uses `GetProcAddress` which doesn't use the import table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `=` as part of a name in C++, but `GetProcAddress` is an OS function which doesn't care about the language that you used. It just does string matching, and not very fancy either. It really cares only about `\0` because that terminates the string. So, if you pass `Z2V0UGFzc3dvcmQ=\0` it will look for an export named `Z2V0UGFzc3dvcmQ=\0`.

The syntax of a linker definition file for `LINK.EXE` won't allow you to add such a name, but again GetProcAddress doesn't care who put the name in the export table. The easiest solution is probably to add `Z2V0UGFzc3dvcmQ_\0` and then overwrite the `_`